# Continuous concave functions

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality, convex-analysis

Let ‎$‎‎f:(0,+‎\infty‎)\to‎\mathbb{R}‎$ ‎be a‎ ‎concave ‎and ‎continuous ‎function. I know that ‎$‎‎f$ ‎satisfies ‎the ‎following inequalities (for all ‎$‎x,y\in(0,‎\infty‎)‎$‎):‎

‎‎
‎(1) ‎$‎‎f(‎\lambda ‎x+(1-‎\lambda) ‎y‎‎)‎\geq‎‎\lambda‎ f(x)+(1-‎\lambda‎)f(y)\;\;;‎0‎<‎\lambda‎‎<1‎‎‎$‎‎

(2) ‎‎$‎‎f(x+h)+f(x-h)-2f(x)‎\leq0 ‎\;\;‎; ‎h‎>0‎‎‎$‎‎

‎
(3) ‎$‎‎‎\frac{‎‎f(x+h_2)-f(x)}{{h_2}}‎‎-‎‎\frac{f(x)-‎‎f(x-h_1)}{{h_1}}\leq0‎\;\;;‎ ‎h_1,h_2‎>0$‎‎‎

‎
(4) ‎$‎‎‎‎‎\frac{‎‎f(x_4)-f(x_3)}{{x_4}-x_3}‎\leq‎‎‎‎\frac{‎‎f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{{x_2}-x_1}\;\;; x_4‎>x_3‎>x_2‎>x_1‎‎‎$‎‎‎‎

‎
(5) ‎$‎\frac{1}{2}(f(x_2)+f(x_1))‎\leq‎‎‎\frac{1}{x_2-x_1}\int_{x_1}^{x_2}f(u)du‎‎\leq‎ f(‎\frac{x_2+x_1}{2}‎)‎‎$‎
‎
In addition, I know that (1) and (4) are equivalent moreover (2) implies  (3) also (3) implies  (4) after that (4) implies (5). Now my question is :‎‎
‎
How can I prove that (2) implies (3) and how about (4) implies (5)? thanks a lot. ‎
‎

Comment: Condition (3) does not make sense. If it is valid for all $h_1,h_2$ you can switch them and come to the conclusion the the difference must be exactly zero, which would mean that $f$ would be constant.

Comment: @  PierreCarre, you are right, I edited that. thank you.

Comment: You have (1) backwards